# C++ WriteProcessMemory() - how to get the right lpBaseAddress?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm making an unofficial patch for a multiplayer game. The game supports only 6 screen resolutions by default, but I found a way to replace them by editing the EXE file with HEX editor. My C++ launcher will start one of 4 .EXE files (one with 16x9, second with 4x3, third with 16:10, etc.). Unfortunately the game generates a checksum and it doesn't allow players to join each other if they use different .EXE files. So I have to replace the generated checksum in RAM. I successfully wiresharked and found what I have to change, for example it's HEX: `dabfe599`.

I use this code:

```
HWND hWnd;
DWORD dwID;
HANDLE hProcess;
hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "GameName");
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwID);
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, dwID);
int value = 0000;
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x0517A69A,
    (LPVOID)&value, sizeof(&value), NULL);
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x0584B078,
    (LPVOID)&value, sizeof(&value), NULL);
```

And it works. Unfortunately: (LPVOID)0x0517A69A and (LPVOID)0x0584B078 are different every time I start the game. So I want to get the LPVOID by searching for the specified HEX (dabfe599) in hProcess. Does anybody know how can I do this?

Comment: What about using ReadProcessMemory to find required address? BTW, it should be sizeof(value)

Comment: If the game is using some simple checksum like xor you could search for stuff in the program you don't care much about (like text strings) and modify these so the crc matches again. For example, if you change byte at offset 0xf100 from orig-val 0 to new-val 1 and the crc changes at only one bit you can try to change byte at offset 0xf200 from x to (x xor (orig-val 0 xor new-val 1)).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. 
Werner, I tried to disable/change/fake checkum in .exe file, but it's too complicated and it seems to be easier to modify by WriteProcessMemory().
Alex, could you please give me an example how to find the required address by ReadProcessMemory()?

Comment: It depends. What are these addresses? Are they addresses in loaded PE modules? Or are they on the process heap?

Comment: If you are familiar with game hacking, you can use the same technique as infinite ammo/life hack to change the checksum to any value you want by riding on the original instruction code in the program that access the checksum. Just redirect the original instruction to a code cave and do your modification there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address you pass to `WriteProcessMemory()` is relative to the base address of the process being written to.  If the address of the checksum changes each time the game is run, it means the checksum is being dynamically allocated in heap memory.  So the only way you are going to write to the checksum is to either:

1. find the game's pointer variable that is pointing at the checksum's memory (or pointing at the checksum's parent if the checksum is part of a larger `struct` or `class`), read the value of that pointer, and then pass it (possibly offsetting it as needed) to `WriteProcessMemory()`.  Hopefully that pointer is at a predictable location, otherwise you may have to follow a whole chain of pointers starting at a known starting location.
2. assuming the checksum is *always* `0xdabfe599`, and `0xdabfe599` does not appear anywhere else in the game's memory, then you could scan through the process's entire memory (or at least its data segments) from start to finish using `ReadProcessMemory()` in a loop until you find `0xdabfe599`, then you will know the address that you read from so you can then write to it.